# Book about lizard people and cat people

Tags: story-identification, books

When I was young I read a book about a humanoid lizard race owning a humanoid feline race as slaves, and the cat people wanted to fight back for freedom. At the end of the book, one of the slaves poisons the lizard queen’s wine and she asks him to drink with her, so he sacrifices himself so his people can escape. Help me find this book!

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this book, and do you have any idea of when it might've been published?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Seems to be the same question: three books, **before 2011**: https://www.sffchronicles.com/threads/532204/ ("looking for the title of sci fi trilogy I reaad years ago.  **three books**, ... is a slave/pet of a lizard-like emperor's daughter. She thinks she lives the good life, somehow gets away, and falls into gladiator life where she becomes the best, eventually becoming a revolutionary in the third book (black I believe, with a picture of the lizard-like now-empress) and overthrows the lizards for many animal species")

Answer (score 5):

Must be [**Alien Chronicles: The Golden One**](https://lucasfilm.fandom.com/wiki/The_Golden_One)
[image]

> Ampris thought her gladiator days were behind her until she discovered
> the truth behind the enslavement of the Aarouns under the
> Viis--causing her to take up arms against tyranny one final time.

[**The Golden One**](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/AlienChronicles)

> A series of Sci-Fi books by Deborah Chester, published by Lucas Film,
> that tells the tale of how a single slave, Ampris, leads an uprising
> against the reptilian Viis, whose cruel empire is undergoing a
> Götterdämmerung, and becomes a legend. It read largely like a cross
> between the Book of Exodus and the story of Spartacus, the
> slave-gladiator who attempted to bring down the Roman Empire

Found in [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/printSF/comments/1apnj1/can_you_help_me_identify_this_1990s_sf_book_about/)

Answer (score 2):

It might be "Exiled: Clan of the Claw" & "By Tooth and Claw", a shared world anthology edited by Bill Fawcett. In this setting, dinosaurs never went extinct - the dinosaurs evolved into the magic-using, coldblooded slave-owning species called the Lishkash. The Mrem are barbarians descended from cat-like mammals. "By Tooth and Claw" has the scenario you describe. An enslaved Mrem named Ranowr, the favorite of the Lishkash princess Hissah, convinces her to drink poison by drinking it first, and the Mrem escape the castle in the ensuing panic.

[image: Cover of "By Tooth and Claw" by S. M. Stirling, Mercedes Lackey, Eric Flint, and Jody Lynn Nye. A green, one-eyed feline warrior wearing a leather breastplate wields a sword, fighting off six raptor-like dinosaurs, some of which are wielding bows and arrows or swords as well.]