# Book series about a race of feline humanoids that were slaves to an advanced race of lizard humanoids

Tags: books, aliens, story-identification

When I was in the Army 25 years ago, I read a series of three books about an alien race of feline humanoids that were slaves to an advanced race of lizard humanoids. The main character was bought as a pet for the daughter of an emperor. They were friends as youths but the main character escaped and started a rebellion. The daughter became empress and both became mortal enemies.

I remember the main character had a litter and the empress was bearing eggs in the final battle. I also remember mentions and characters of other races in the universe of the books. It was a trilogy and I think the title had 'alien' in it but I’m not sure about that part. I would love to read these books again. This has bothered me for years, lol. Thank you.

Comment: Is it the same as [Book about lizard people and cat people](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/255516/book-about-lizard-people-and-cat-people)?

Comment: @Gabe - If anyone correctly identifies the story you're looking for, you can mark that answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 4):

Is this the ***[Alien Chronicles](https://www.goodreads.com/series/60527-lucasfilm-s-alien-chronicles)*** trilogy...?

- Book 1: *[The Golden One](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/58436.The_Golden_One)* (1997):
- Book 2: *[The Crimson Claw](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/202357.The_Crimson_Claw)* (1998)
- Book 3: *[The Crystal Eye](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/202356.The_Crystal_Eye)* (1999)

From [TV Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/AlienChronicles):

> *The Alien Chronicles* - also known as *Lucasfilm's Alien Chronicles* - is a trilogy of Sci-Fi novels by Deborah Chester, published by Lucasfilm. **The books tell the tale of how a single Aaroun slave, Ampris, leads an uprising against the reptilian Viis and their cruel but crumbling empire, becoming a legend to the abiru - the various species enslaved by the Viis - in the process.** It reads largely like a cross between the Book of Exodus and the story of Spartacus, the slave-gladiator who attempted to bring down the Roman Empire, in space!

From a [review](https://www.theforce.net/books/reviews/thegoldenone.asp) of the first book:

> This novel, the first of a trilogy, takes place outside of the Star Wars "universe," but its story and characters definitely appeal to Star Wars fans. The Golden One touches on universal themes, such as imperialism, slavery, class-based societies, childhood dreams and nightmares, and the journey into adulthood.
>
> The main character of the story is Ampris, otherwise known as the Golden One. **Ampris is a pet of an imperial daughter named Israi. Ampris is of a cat-like race called Aarouns and Israi is the daughter of the Kaa -- the ruler of the Viis, a reptilian race that has ruled the Viis homeworld and surrounding planets for centuries, keeping the other "inferior" races in servitude. You watch as Ampris and Israi grow up together and begin seeing the world through the eyes of adults, instead of the wide-eyed innocence of childhood.**